# Form submission not working on mobile Flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I've looked but can't find someone with the same problem.
I'm developing a small webpage using Flask. Everything works completely fine on my laptop but as soon as I test it (on localhost) with my phone (Safari) errors pop up (see below)

The error only comes up when I submit the form at that point and error appears on safari and in the terminal. I need to reload the page for everything to come back to normal. Weirdly sometimes it works completely fine.

Here's the python (3.10) code:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/<tipe>",methods=['GET','POST'])
def index(tipe=None):
     return render_template('index.html',img=None,alt=str(tipe))

@app.route("/submission",methods=['GET','POST'])
def handelsubmit():
     print(request.form.get("check1"))
     return render_template('Submission accepted.html',alt="got")
```

And here you can find the Html (index.html and submission accepted.html are pretty much the same thing)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.css') }}">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ButtonContainer">
      <a class="Button" href="/Exos">Exos</a>
    </div>

    <form action="{{ url_for('handelsubmit') }}" method="POST">
      <div id ="demo" class= "slider">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="on" checked><label> chapA</label></div>
        <input type="submit">

    </form>
    <h1>{{alt}}</h1>
    <img src="{{img}}" alt=" {{alt}}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Error with safari (only when i submit the form)
`"POST /submission HTTP/1.1" 400`

Comment: I also have this same problem!, Did you find a solution?